# (Very) high temperature

Tags: adjectifs, superlatifs

Are the following translations are correct, for a temperature?

> High → *haut* or *élevé*
>   Very high → *très haut*

Comment: Sorry to get picky with the context, but is it “temperature” as in “fever” (in which case I’d probably use “une fièvre/température [très] élevée” more often than “ … [très] haute”);  for discussing  air temperature (in which case I don’t know which one would be more common); or for adjusting thermostats/ovens/etc (in which case I think “haut[e]” would be more common )? Regardless, I think they are both good, nearly interchangeable translations, but, as suggested above, one might be preferable over another depending on what kind of temperature you’re talking about.

Comment: I was talking about weather temperature. Thank you alot for your
detailed explanation.

Comment: I'm glad it was about the weather because that's the one I had no idea about and Cerceus' good answer covers it well. (PS Please don't rely too heavily on my "explanations" concerning the other two contexts... they were primarily just expressions of the "feelings" of an anglophone)

Comment: I understand :) Thanks again Papa Poule

Comment: As a francophone, I confirm your remarks on contexts are totally correct, @PapaPoule, yet a bit literary. For spoken French, it is common to hear "Il a beaucoup de fièvre" (even though fever should not be quantifiable, but we discussed this kind of things on another topic). As for oven, recipes often provide a precise temperature or range. Maybe this could be included in an answer to make it as exhaustive as possible.

Comment: Très bien vu, @Chop ! C’est vrai que tout ça (discussion de ‘levels of happiness, blues, & now fever’) se ressemble.  En plus elle me fait penser à une autre question récente sur « beaucoup de/beaucoup des » et à une ‘exception’ (totalement nulle et hors contexte, d’accord) où « beaucoup DES » marcherait bien en parlant des « bleus » : « La France attend beaucoup des Bleus (l’équipe) cette année ». Pas mal, hein ? All kidding aside, thanks for the kind and gentle review of my earlier comment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of temperatures, you'll use *élevé*/*très élevé* or *chaud*/*très chaud*. You could consider something like *caniculaire* for *very high*, but that is a little more literary.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the context:

- La température est très élevée. (Pretty general use) (La température extérieure est très élevée.) (La température du four est très élevée.) (Sa température (corporelle) est très élevée = Il a de la fièvre).
- L'eau est chauffée à très haute température. (NB: UHT = Ultra Haute Température, used for milk)
- Il fait très chaud aujourd'hui.
- C'est la canicule !
- Vous trouverez des températures caniculaires sur la Côte d'Azur et dans le Midi-Pyrénées. (Nobody speak like that, only the weather forecaster do)
- Conservez vos aliments à basse température. = Conservez vos aliment au froid/frais. (Froid is colder than frais. Basse température is not so precise, it can be cold or cool)

Comment: +1 for emphasizing the importance of context. Unrelated to the question, but since you brought up the difference between 'froid' and 'frais', maybe you could help me determine where 'frette', as used in Quebec, fits in on the scale of low temperatures: between frais and froid? synonymous with froid? or even colder than froid? Thanks!

Comment: "Frette" in Quebec is the equivalent to "froid" in France. http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/frette